# CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response

Tags: php, cakephp, oauth, cakephp-2.0

This code only works if I do a simple post or get request.

```
   public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) { 
        //some code - facebook
    }
```

But in my case I have two options. Login through facebook or the normal login (form).

At the moment the problem is that when I click to submit the form the function authenticate  will be also executed. So my question is: how can i detect what is the name of the Post request? something like `isset($_POST['submitted_fb']`

The main problem is that function is always called when I do any Post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication only occour when you are not logged in, or, have not permission to view a page.

Do a validation like this:

```
public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) { 
     if($request->data['loginType'] == 'facebook') {
         // Do facebook login
     } else {
         // Do form login
     }
}
```

and add a hidden form to your view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('loginType', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => 'facebook'));
```